# I am trying to read a csv file in java. Below is my code

Tags: java, csv

```
final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(entry)));
String line = "";

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("line" + line);

    final String[] rows = line.split(",");
```

this is my csv file

```
" 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015","RaceSummary","Page:1","Id","Race","Type","Rot.","District","PrideFor","ArtSeq","ReportSeq","Content","Type","Md","Bar Group","1","LINC ADAPTER SECTION 4","Content","N","A - ARLIN","1","1","1","Oscar James, Sr.","Content","0","<N.P.>"
```

i am trying to print the column which i mentioned in the csv.But i dont know why my out put is getting upto "Pride" as one line and "For" as another line like that it was repeating for the next two values ("ArtSeq","ReportSeq").Can any one suggest me where i went wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: When you print the line, what exactly prints? Can you show us the output? As far as I can see here should not be a split between Pride and For in the column, unless there is something wrong with the input. Also maybe show us what you are using to show the data (printing it I presume?)

Comment: line" 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015","Race Summary","Page: 1","Id","Race","Type","Rot.","District","Pride
lineFor","Art
lineSeq","Report
lineSeq","Content","Type","Md","Bar Group","1","LINC ADAPTER SECTION 4","Content","N","A - ARLIN","1","1","1","Oscar James, Sr.","Content","0","<N.P.>"     this is the output i am getting

Comment: You are better off using a CSV library, rather than writing your own. To do it properly, there are many cases that you will need to address (e.g., quoting/not quoting, whitespace between items, embedded quote marks, etc.)

Comment: Mike Harris did you observe i am getting the new line in this place ("PrideFor
") i think its because of the uppercase Pride"For"

Comment: I doubt it - simply because you have many other upper cased strings (such as ReportSeq, ArtSeq, etc) that don't do this.

Comment: ypu are correct i am getting the problem at those three values only(PrideFor,ReportSeq and ArtSeq )

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your input you have second value have commas "Aug 20, 2015" this leads to more numbers of splits than that you expect. 
Example : 
You would expect this " 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015" to be 2 parts but it will be three

```
[0]" 9:42:43AM"
[1]"Aug 20
[2] 2015"
```

You can change you split to be

```
line.split("\",\"");
```

I believe that should solve your problem.

Comment: But that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: line" 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015","Race Summary","Page: 1","Id","Race","Type","Rot.","District","Pride
lineFor","Art
lineSeq","Report
lineSeq","Content","Type","Md","Bar Group","1","LINC ADAPTER SECTION 4","Content","N","A - ARLIN","1","1","1","Oscar James, Sr.","Content","0","<N.P.>" i am getting output like this

Comment: Perhaps, but it is still a very large issue with the code that should be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you provided...

```
line" 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015","Race Summary","Page: 1","Id","Race","Type","Rot.","District","Pride 
lineFor","Art lineSeq","Report lineSeq","Content","Type","Md","Bar Group","1","LINC ADAPTER SECTION 4","Content","N","A - ARLIN","1","1","1","Oscar James, Sr.","Content","0","<N.P.>"
```

Considering it is different then your input, I'd guess there might be a special character or something on the input file (for example, a tab or line spaceing). This is causing your while loop to read the first line (up to the line break), and then read the next line. If you put both of these onto the same line in the file it will probably work better.

I should clarify as well, nothing in the code you posted would cause this behaviour, it is either somewhere else in your code or in the file itself.

Comment: " 9:42:43AM","Aug 20, 2015","Race Summary","Page: 1","Id","Race","Type","Rot.","District","Pride
For","Art
Seq","Report
Seq","Content","Type","Md","Bar Group","1","LINC ADAPTER SECTION 4","Content","N","A - ARLIN","1","1","1","Oscar James, Sr.","Content","0","<N.P.>" this is the output.it seems uppercase issue in these three values.the line gets breaked and printing in a new line at this three values

Comment: Have a look at your file in hex, and see if there's a character between Pride/For, Art/Seq, and Report/Seq. If this file came from a spreadsheet, it's quite possible that there's a CR or an LF character between the words so that in the spreadsheet it shows as one word above the other. In Windows you won't normally see this as a new line with something like Notepad, because Windows needs two characters to mark a new line, a CR and an LF. Java isn't Windows-specific, so it'll recognise any of the combinations as a new line.

Comment: john Bickers i just checked my file in hex editor there is "." in between the two characters

Comment: it just looks like this "Pride.For, Art.Seq,Report.Seq"

Comment: I assume those are whats breaking your code. Delete them if possible, or rewrite those parts of the string. I have a bet it will fix your problem.